# Deriving expression for free energy of harmonic restraint

Tags: thermodynamics, partition-function, molecular-dynamics

I want to derive the expression for the free energy of adding a harmonic restraint between two molecules in solution. This restraint is of the form $V = \frac12K(r-r_0)^2$.

In particular, I am doing (classical) molecular dynamics simulations to find the binding energy of molecule A to B. To avoid dissociation, I add a harmonic potential between one atom of A and one atom of B. I then find the binding free energy by Free Energy Perturbation (FEP), which involves "turning off" intermolecular interactions of B with the system. When B is not interacting with the system anymore, it is possible to find an analytical solution of the free energy of the restraint, yet I can't find the derivation for it.

[Boresch *et al.*](https://doi.org/10.1021/jp0217839) have derived an expression for a much more complicated restraint, and [Mobley](https://doi.org/10.1063/1.2221683) casually mentioned that what I'm trying to do is easy, yet I haven't been able to piece it together.

What we want to do if find the free energy $\Delta G_r$ of the reaction:
$A_\text{solv}\cdots B_\text{gas} \rightarrow A_\text{solv} + B_\text{gas}$, where the dots stand for the harmonic restraint. Thus:

$$\Delta G_r = -k_BT \ln\left(\frac{Z_AZ_B}{Z_{A \cdots B}} \right).$$

The trick that Boresch *et al.* use is to have a restraint that allows a factorization of the partition function:

$Z_{A \cdots B} = Z_A \cdot Z_B \cdot Z_R$, where $Z_R$ is the partition function for the restraint. If I am not mistaken, $Z_R$ should be:

$$Z_R = \int_0^\pi \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\infty} r^2 \sin(\theta) \exp\left(-\frac{K(r-r_0)^2}{k_BT}\right)\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\phi \,\mathrm d\theta.$$

This corresponds to the integral over all space in spherical coordinates of the restraint's potential. However, it seems like this coordinate change must be applied to $Z_B$ somehow for the whole expression to remain coherent. I'm not too sure how to go about all of this.

Comment: I cannot access any of the papers from home. Do you need to compute $Z_R$) (i.e. to solve the integral) or?

Comment: Yes, $Z_R$ should end up in the final expression for the free energy of the restraint. $Z_A$ and $Z_B$ should be cancelled out somehow